# Other than flagging a question should I do anything else with this user?

Tags: discussion, support, offensive

I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732485/python-did-gay-sperm-influence-the-python-terminlogy-tuple question which is somewhat offensive and certainly not a question that belongs on the site. I flagged it for a moderator to have a look at, but can't seem to find any guide on whether I should do anything further?

In this case, I am assuming that posting it here will get a mod on the case pretty quickly, but in future, is it just a case of flagging it as per normal and that is enough, or should I do something more?

Comment: Flagging is just fine. That's really all you need to do.

Comment: Heh, this particular user has an unnatural fixation on Python, Stack Overflow and ABBA. We like our trolls well rounded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be seeing more questions like this in the future as they're coming from a known troll, so just flag them as offensive whenever you come across them. The idea is to get them deleted as soon as possible so we don't waste too much time.